# How to secure methods annotated with @StreamListener?

Tags: java, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm developing a web application based on microservices architecture. Its primary framework is Spring Cloud Data Flow, microservices are communicating with each other via message bus (RabbitMQ), REST-endpoints are exposed only by a gateway wjich is also a central point of authentication.

I want to follow the global authentication, local authorization approach using OAuth2 tokens, but a problem has occurred: I don't understand how to configure authorization process on microservices a.k.a use @PreAuthorize on methods annotated with @StreamListener, and I can't find any examples for this.